# Why is it not allowed to use a ROLLBACK statement in a PL/SQL trigger, but RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR is?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, rollback

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I was under the impression that a call to RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR() forces a ROLLBACK. How is it possible that a call to RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR() is allowed in PL/SQL triggers when ROLLBACK statements and/or methods that execute ROLLBACK statements are not?

I have the feeling I am missing a crucial point here :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am giving a course on PL/SQL (it's my first year) and the book we use (Dutch) specifies that a ROLLBACK is done after a call to RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(). I think I will have to speak to the authors to clarify the difference of a statement "rollback" and a real ROLLBACK :)

Comment: Allow me to just add that a `commit` or `rollback` inside a trigger is very bad practice. If the trigger finds something wrong, it should raise an informative exception and allow the code surrounding the DML statement to determine what, if anything, should be done. Based on conditions the trigger cannot be aware of, the best course of action could be continue on, perform a partial rollback or abort the entire operation. These are not decisions that can be properly made by a trigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider yourself corrected. Sort of. Raising (or encountering) an exception doesn't cause a rollback of the curent transaction. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#CIHGJCFI):

> In most cases, if a trigger runs a statement that raises an exception, and the exception is not handled by an exception handler, then the database rolls back the effects of both the trigger and its triggering statement.

Note that it's the statement, not the transaction; but "roles back the effect of" is a little confusing I suppose...

There is an implicit savepoint around every statement, and the trigger exception rolls back to that savepoint (except for `after` triggers etc. as noted in the docs). From Tom Kyte's *Expert Oracle Database Architecture*:

> Oracle achieves this statement-level atomicity by silently wrapping a SAVEPOINT aroind each of our calls to the database.

Answer (score 2):

Inside a trigger a RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR does not perform a ROLLBACK, it aborts the current operation, i.e. a single UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE. Everything inside a trigger belongs to such an operation (thats' also the reason for famous error "ORA-04091 - Table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it").

A Rollback reverts all changes within current transaction (or up to given Savepoint), that's different.